# Unable to use pdftex-quiet package

Tags: pdftex, packages, installing, bash, command-line

I'm trying to use the pdftex-quiet package from the command line. It is correctly installed also and comes with TexLive 2019. But I am not able to use it and get the error message

> 'pdftex-quiet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Bash is installed. In the end I want to use it in a makefile for my Latex-project. thx in advance!

Comment: Presumably (you don't say) you are using texlive on windows. When you say bash is installed do you mean you have  a native windows bash or that you have the wsl enabled? In the latter case I doubt it will work as the  file paths will differ, but I don't have a windows texlive to test.

Comment: I am using TexLive on Windows and installed Git Bash seperately.

Comment: you would need bash  to be in your windows bath and a windows wrapper executable for the script (as you can't just make a symbolic link as on other platforms) (the win32 distribution may already have such a wrapper but it looks not from the error you show.

Comment: why do you need this at all can't your makefile just call pdflatex--interaction=batchmode ?

Comment: batchmode is fine I think. I thought there might be a better solution because there are still some messages coming up if I use pdflatex. imo this is about optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a binary in windows for it. But I found a script in the scripts folder and it seems to work. I could make a small binary wrapper by creating a copy of `runscript.exe` with the name `pdftex-quiet.exe` and then this call worked in a bash (the error is intentional ...):

```
$ pdftex-quiet -fmt=pdflatex test-utf8

l.154   \someerror


Transcript written on test-utf8.log.

---------------------------------------------
- Failed to compile the provided TEX file! --
---------------------------------------------
C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 1:
bash c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\pdftex-quiet\pdftex-quiet -fmt=pdflatex test-utf8
```

I don't know how to make a wrapper `pdflatex-quiet`.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works. Is it possible to run pdflatex quietly in cmd AND get error messages? I didn't find a satisfying solution yet. I think the pdflatex-quiet package would be great, but I thought maybe there is a solution I would't have to use Git Bash.